# How to use the same form partial for registration and editing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a site on PHP which I want to convert to Rails. I use md5 for password storage and _form partial for registration and edit users data. I made login and password fields required, thats work perfect for registration but when user try to edit his data, something like login, password field again need to fill (password field has password type and stay blank for editing). How I can use those form and solve problem with password enter in edit mode ?

Comment: Normally you don't fill the password fields when editing profile. You leave them blank and say: "if you want to **change** your password, fill the new password here and here"

Comment: but i need for that another _form partial ?

Comment: What exactly do you want ? you want to store encrypted password (with md5) on editing ?

Comment: i want to use my _form partial for edit, that form i use for registration users. how i can allow to avoid password filling in edit mode. may be I must to specify my password field in model?

Comment: "but i need for that another _form partial ?" Yes so you can test your current `@user` if it is a new_record. I guess in your controller you set the `@user` variable to current_user or to `User.new`. Then: in your view, add a if statement to display the password field: `if @user.new_record?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model, add a validation on your password fields only if they've been filled in, in other words, on update, the fields can be blank.  If they are blank, then they will not be validated or changed.

```
validates :password, 
          :confirmation => true, 
          :length => {:within => 8..20}, 
          :allow_blank => true, 
          :on => :update
```

You may also want to add a note on the form, the password fields are only required if you are changing your password or your email address.

You can check `object.new_record?` (as Mr Yoshiji mentions) to determine if it's a new record (no id yet) or an existing record to change your form hints.

Comment: i try to use your code, i think its good and flexible, but validates not work, just ignore :password, if I add something like validates :email, :presence => true, rails give an error: Email can't be blank, but nothing about password, why rails ignore password ?

Comment: oh, i forgot that i use md5 hash function, and nil pass field crypting like normal string